# ASP.NET MVC: How to handle 400 bad request error when url end with %

Tags: asp.net, bad-request

I am trying to handle all HTTP errors to my custom error pages, but I find that when there is a % at the end of url, i cannot use config setting or code to handle it, 
for example: http://localhost/abc%
the response is:
Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

So, can we use config setting or c# code to handle this error request?

Comment: What version of IIS do you use? You can also configure custom error pages in IIS itself.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5, asp.net 4.0.

Comment: This error should never occur in real life. Have you seen that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this 4 part series for configuring custom error pages within IIS: http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-Custom-Error-in-IIS-7-75.aspx.

I personally prefer to use [Application_Error event](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355) to log the errors and redirect user to custom error pages. Note that you need to use integrated pipe-line in IIS to catch all errors otherwise IIS will show its own error page for resources that are not served by ASP.NET.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the wrong answer. I have XP machine currently that shows 404 for % sign so couldn't verify above. Searching over internet, I found that it's simply **not possible to display custom error page for 400 status code**. See [this question from server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url) for more information.

Comment: Hi VinayC, thanks for the quick response, but looks like this solution doesn't work for the requests ending with %, are you sure it works?

Comment: @Andy, appologies for wrong answer. Apparently, its not possible to have custom error page for 400 status code. See this link for more info: http://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url

Answer (score 4):

Who said not possible?

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

OR

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985327/asp-net-web-api-httpresponseexception-400-bad-request-hijacked-by-iis)