# Handling bad request in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a api url like below in my mvc4 app

```
http://localhost:15839/api/mydata/getdata/3365895543/PROBLEMDATA/myotherparam
```

Now client is consuming the above url to send `httprequest`. In response `api` is sending back a `response`. but in `PROBLEMDATA` of the url user is sending bad characters that are giving me `Bad Request - Invalid URL`. I can't force my client source to encode data. i need to handle it in my web api and give back my client a string `"Unsucessful"`. I have seen [this](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/ASP.NET-Web-API-Poster.pdf) webapi cycle wondering at which point I should handle this. probably at http message handler but How?

I may need to follow [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers). but `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` also doesn't get hit

Comment: did you want the request to reach the *intended* api controller or just handle the error better?

Comment: If request can reach the controller that is will be great Other wise i wan to send json response "unscussful" back to client

Comment: That last link you provided (`DelegatingHandler`) doesnt appear to help anyway because a 400 bad request is validated *before* it hits this. It may be impossible to do what you want to do in web api - its probably best to ask this on the dedicated web api forum: http://forums.asp.net/1246.aspx/1?ASP+NET+Web+API

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can capture this globally by overriding the [application_error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355) method.  From there I suppose you could produce the "unsucessful" response or pass the request along to be handled at the controller level.

[Take a look at this question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511239/asp-net-mvc-how-to-handle-400-bad-request-error-when-url-end-with).

Comment: how would you 'pass the request along to be handled at the controller level' ?

Comment: @wal either by using Response.Redirect or by declaring the appropriate controller as an IController and using the execute method.  By doing some regex branching off the RawUrl you could guess where you need to send the response or send the request to an error controller as a lost resort.

Comment: thats not ideal as you now need to do a quasi-implementation of the api routing to get to the right controller

Comment: [According to this](http://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url) it looks like the request is unlikely to make it to the application level at all.

Comment: Request is not reaching the controller. I think i should follow http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers this but it is also not working